# Angular Reactive Forms - Enabled/Disabled Form Control not correctly reflected on UI after FormGroup is Re-initialized

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formgroups, angular-formbuilder

I have a test angular reactive form, where you can enable/disable a Form Control, and apply required/optional validation.

I am running into an issue where the FormControl enabled/disabled state is not correctly reflected in the UI when re-initializing the reactive form.

Example Setup:

```
first_name: AbstractControl;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.buildForm();
}

buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      first_name: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: false }, [
        Validators.maxLength(10),
      ]),
    });

    this.first_name = this.form.controls.first_name;
}
```

By default, the control is enabled, so I have a method to disable the control

```
disable(): void {
    this.first_name.disable();
}
```

I want to be able to reset this form group back to the original state, so I call "buildForm()" and "updateValueAndValidity()" to re-initialize the form.

```
rebuild() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

- This resets the value, validators, and enabled/disabled state of each form control.
- Everything appears to be correctly reset in the form, however, the enabled/disabled state is NOT correctly reflected on the UI
- As a result, the input is still disabled in the UI, even though the control is correctly reset back to enabled.

I have found a workaround, shown below, although having to call:

- Call form.reset(), and set the disabled state back to the original value BEFORE re-initializing the form. This seems like it should not be required.

```
reset() {
    this.form.reset({
      first_name: { value: '', disabled: false },
    });
}

rebuild() {
    this.reset();
    this.buildForm();
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

I would use form.reset() alone, however, it does not allow the original validators to be re-applied, so I would have to call control.setValidators for each control. I would like to have a single piece of logic for initializing and re-initializing the form.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzxcpb)

To reproduce:

- The Input field is enabled by default
- Click "Disable", and the input is now disabled
- Click "Rebuild Form". The input remains disabled, even though the form control itself is not disabled

So, my question is,

- Is there a way to ensure the input field correctly reflects a controls enabled/disabled state when the form is re-initialized without needing to call form.reset()?

Comment: But it's working even without calling `this.reset();`...

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly In the linked Stackblitz app, if you disable the Input field, it is NOT re-enabled in the UI if the rebuild() method does not call this.reset();. What interaction are you seeing?

Comment: Did you found a fix for this issue, @JamesBV3?  I'm facing same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue, I had to use `ngAfterContentChecked()` and run through my subscriptions again.
I would like to find the cause to get a real fix.

Comment: Hi Desmith, please check again is this a clear answer? and this might be a comment instead of an answer.